# Linux memory issue

Tags: linux, ls, linux-disk-free

I have a problem on my server.

When i try to start my server, it says that "there no left space on device"

If i execute the command "df", I see that on directory if full.

```
/dev/mapper/owegdc_vg-owegdc_logs_lv
                  10321208 9797004         0 100% /opt/application/owegdc/logs
```

When i get to the logs directory here what i see

```
ls -lrta
total 368
drwxr-x---  2 oweadm grpowe  16384 Jan 15  2014 lost+found
drwxr-x---  7 oweadm grpowe   4096 Jun 18 11:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  2 oweadm grpowe  12288 Aug  4 10:20 apache
drwxr-xr-x  2 oweadm grpowe   4096 Aug  5 00:56 batches
drwxr-xr-x  2 oweadm grpowe   4096 Sep 10 13:43 expl
drwxr-xr-x  2 oweadm grpowe 327680 Sep 10 13:50 jonas
drwxr-xr-x 11 oweadm grpowe   4096 Sep 10 13:50 ..
```

```
du -sk
9642792 .
```

I tried things like 'lsof' but it didn't work...

Do you have an idea ?

Thx

Comment: I have lots of ideas.  In which ones are you interested?  Please tell us more about what puzzles you or what you need help with.  Currently you only tell us that you have a full disk (and some more details about that full disk).  I would suggest to remove some files to fix this, but this is so obvious that I think you have something else on your mind which I cannot read out of your post.

Comment: Souldn't this question be asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: I woulk like to free some space on my disk because it says it is full but i can't find the file that are responsibles of my full disk

Comment: I would say all of them, more or less :)

Comment: @LaHu I suggest to consider what "X.L.Ant" wrote to you, he has right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try something like

```
du | sort -h -r
```

That would list the directories on your disk, ordered by their size descending. The first directory in the output list is the biggest one.

Better, if you're looking for large single files instead of a directory, [this answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53738) gives useful information, especially this:

```
find . -type f  | xargs du -h | sort -rn
```

The output is the same, but it lists files instead of dirs.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it showed me that 'batches' was the heavies directory in fact :-)